# Как удалить ненужные символы в шрифте формата TTF?

Tags: шрифты

Как удалить ненужные символы в шрифте формата TTF?

У меня есть шрифт, там много ненужных для меня символов. Могу ли я как-то удалить их отуда?

Comment: Ээээ... А зачем удалять? Чем они мешают?

Comment: @VladD      Мешают конечно Зачем они будут там .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Скачиваем бесплатную программу [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/).

---

2. Запускаем ее и выбираем нужный шрифт.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

3. С зажатым <kbd>Shift</kbd> мышью выбираем нужные символы.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

4. Инвертируем выделение: <kbd>Правка</kbd>→<kbd>Выделить</kbd>→<kbd>Инвертировать выделение</kbd>

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

5. Удаляем ненужные символы: <kbd>Кодировка</kbd>→<kbd>Отцепить и удалить символы...</kbd>

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

6. Вместо символов должны появиться зачеркнутые квадраты:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

7. Сохраняем шрифт.

---

Основано на ответе к вопросу: ["how to remove characters from a font file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12976510/2486051)

Comment: быть может вы подскажете, [как добавить неразрывный пробел в шрифт, если его там нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790358/%D0%92-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE)

Comment: Нашла ответ благодаря вашему ответу