# В подключенном шрифте не показывается конкретный символ

Tags: html, css, шрифты

По какой причине может не отображаться в подключенном шрифте конкретный символ?
 В моем случае это неразрывный пробел `&nbsp;`. Использую локально подключенный шрифт "Futuris". При добавлении обычного пробела показывается разрыв между словами. Но при добавлении неразрывного пробела (даже нескольких) именно в жирном начертании разрыва не отображается. Подключаю вот таким образом:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Futuris';
  src: url('Futuris-Bold.eot');
  src: url('Futuris-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('Futuris-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('Futuris-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('Futuris-Bold.svg#Futuris-Bold') format('svg'),
  url('Futuris-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Futuris', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>а&nbsp;бб&nbsp;ввв</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

К сожалению, не смогла сделать пример воспроизводимым здесь, так как сюда загрузить шрифт нельзя. Подозреваю, что можно вручную как-то исправить файл шрифта, например - *.ttf добавив туда пробел, но не знаю как это сделать правильно. Может быть существует способ повесить стиль на спецсимвол?

[Воспроизводимый пример](http://kizoso.ru/template/evrtrkiw9e3ywioq2/).

---

UPD: [Если можно удалить символ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535148/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-ttf?rq=1) с помощью [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), то получается можно и добавить, но где и как в таблице найти неразрывный пробел?

[image: FontForge: Futuris-Bold.ttf]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это ошибка в самом шрифте, т. е. проблема не будет воспроизводиться после выхода новой, исправленной версии шрифта.

Comment: @Arhad думаю, данный вопрос может помочь тем, кто встретится с подобной проблемой в другом шрифте, можно изменить заголовок на другой, охватывающий аудиторию шире, например не про пробел, а вообще про символ.

Comment: Тогда отзываю голос за закрытие. Однако расширение на случай с любым символом, возможно, потребует переписывания и тела вопроса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Скачала бесплатную программу [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/). Открыла проблемный шрифт в формате *.ttf. Нашла символ неразрывного пробела, его номер в юникоде: `U+00A0`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жму на символ, смотрю. Действительно, ширины у этого символа нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю ширину, сохраняю шрифт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конвертируем получившийся Futuris-Bold.sfd в нужные форматы. [Работает](http://kizoso.ru/template/fioeiye78w099dush/). Единственный момент, нужно подобрать ширину неразрывного пробела, чтобы он не отличался от ширины разрывного.

Comment: но это уже получается авторский шрифт, то есть нужно, чтобы пользователи уже имели его на своем ПК? Или вы его будете добавлять на какой-то сетевой ресурс?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, да, шрифт получается измененный уже. Думаю нужно написать автору(если его будет легко найти) - так как скорее всего он в жирном начертании просто пропустил этот символ. В других начертаниях этот символ есть. Да, шрифт подключается локально.